# Настройка VSC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Не подскажете, как в `VSC++ Express` подставить в настройках параметр, чтобы при вводе, допустим, цикла `for` и открытия скобки, высвечивались параметры цикла `(стандартные (i=0;i<10;i++))`, или, например, пишу структуру dom, и когда обращаюсь к ее содержимому, выпадало меню с ее содержимым?

Comment: Для начала, выучили бы русский язык, т.к, в вашем относительно небольшом вопросе мне пришлось исправить более десятка ошибок.

---------------
Во вторых - нихрена не понятно, что вам нужно: и DOM привинтили, и цикл, и параметры среды Visual Studio....что вам надо?

Comment: @Asen Вы еще 4 ошибки пропустили :)

Comment: Спасибо за критику и исправления, я спрашиваю где поставить галочку чтобы при наборе кода подсвечивались подсказки, и можно было выбрать значение, как например когда набираю #include <~~~ Здесь выпадает меню с результатом ~~~~>

Comment: Для этого есть отличная вещь - Visual Assist X
http://www.wholetomato.com/ . Пользуюсь - нравится. Заменяет стандартный IntelliSense.

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но он не работает с Express версией т.к. это плагин, а как можно расширить возможности IntelliSense?

Comment: http://www.ogre3d.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4711 Тут поговаривают про обновление, но лучше уже поставить полную версию, тем более что можно достать её бесплатно и лицензионно http://www.dreamspark.ru/